# Why is Harrison Wells the reverse flash in season 5 of Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash*: Eobard Thawne is the reverse flash. It is revealed that he went back in time to kill Barry's mother and then was stuck in the past. He kills the actual Harrison Wells and take his form and waits for Barry to become the Flash. At the end of the season, he was erased from existence.

In season 5 of The Flash, Reverse Flash is seen in a cage in the future, here he is in the form of Harrison Wells.

How is that possible?

Comment: Time Travel...s'weird.!

Comment: He also appears in the Crisis on Earth-X event. I imagine they'll have some explanation at the end of the series since technically the entire plot of the Flash season 1 was his inability to travel through time.  My guess it will be "Because..... Speed Force!"

Answer (score 4):

The answer to every such question is: "Speed force".

Jokes aside, it seems they wanted Tom to play the role and they did.

From [comicbook.com](https://comicbook.com/dc/2019/01/20/the-flash-season-5-eobard-thawne-nora-west-allen-tom-cavanagh/)

> "No, we love Matt — he’s fantastic as Reverse-Flash, too." Helbing explained. "But it’s funny, if you plot out the Thawne timeline — I think there’s a version of this online somewhere — it makes more sense, logically, in a weird, time-travel way, that this is the Thawne that we see. Also, the whole theme of this season is “legacy,” so it felt more applicable in the way that we introduce Reverse-Flash, as Wells, for it to play out that way with Tom."

That's what they had to say about it.

Answer (score 3):

Barry Allen traveled two times to the past in order to get help from Eobard Thawne:

- Once for having help to defeat Zoom during the season 2.
- Once, with Barry's future daughter, Nora West-Allen, for getting help to defeat Cicada in the season 5.

Thanks to these events (which happened at the same time, within the secret room), Eobard understood that it will be defeated in the near future by the Team Flash.

Knowing that, he entered into the negative Speed Force when Eddie Thawne committing suicide, preventing him to be erased from the timeline, in contrary of the first season where he didn't live the two events I talked above.

Then, he left the Speed Force, arriving some times after the events of the season 5, still with the body of Harrisson Wells.

Finally, he has been thrown in prison for some reasons somewhen around 2049 (Nora's original timeline).